# Mongoose updateOne not saving

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

From what I can see it looks like Mongoose is adding it, however when I check the backend of the server nothing is there, no errors are showing, just what is below when I ask for the result.

```
{ n: 1,
  nModified: 0,
  upserted: [ { index: 0, _id: 5e369aa7bcc3e15c0f1d030b } ],
  opTime:
   { ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1580636839 },
     t: 14 },
  electionId: 7fffffff000000000000000e,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime':
   { clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1580636839 },
     signature: { hash: [Object], keyId: [Object] } },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1580636839 } }
```

Here is the code

```
const userData = {"UUID": query.uuid, "ipaddress":ip, "station":req.params.stationname};
     var update = {'$set':{
         "endtime":Date.now()
        }},
       options = { upsert: true};

 Listeners.updateOne(userData, update, options, function(error, result) {
             console.log(result);
             if (!error) {
                 // If the document doesn't exist
                 if (!result) {
                     // Create it
                     result = new Listeners(userData);            
                    // Save the document
                    result.save(function(error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            // Do something with the document
                        } else {
                            throw error;
                        }
                    });
                }
             }
             else{
              console.log(error);
             }
            });
```

I have also tried the following

```
const userData = {"UUID": query.uuid, "ipaddress":ip, "station":req.params.stationname};
 result = new Listeners(userData);            
                // Save the document
                result.save(function(error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        // Do something with the document
                    } else {
                        throw error;
                    }
                });
```

The response I get is

```
{ _id: 5e369e790cd7d60a7eef12c4,
  UUID: '14456',
  ipaddress: '::ffff:101.118.4.209',
  station: 'PERTHRadio',
  starttime: 2020-02-02T10:03:37.839Z }
```

This is the mongoose.model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// define the User model schema
const ListenerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    UUID: {
        type: String,
       // index: { unique: true }
      },
    ipaddress: {
      type: String,
     // index: { unique: true }
    },
    station: {type:String},
    starttime:{
        type: Date,
    },
    endtime:{
        type: Date, 
    }
  }, { collection: 'listeners'});


  /**
 * The pre-save hook method.
 */
ListenerSchema.pre('save', function saveHook(next) {
    if (!this.starttime) {
        this.starttime = new Date();
    }
//    return this
  console.log(this)
  next();
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('listeners', ListenerSchema);
```

Comment: `updateOne` with `upsert: true` simply creates a new value if there's no match between your query parameters and existing database documents and that's what happens in your case (`nModified: 0`, `nUpserted`: ...). Just make sure that there is already a document in your database which contains all the passed values.

Comment: @mickl So your suggestion is to remove the upsert part?

Comment: @mickl why is the save not working tho?

Comment: Please check if your  userData `{"UUID": query.uuid, "ipaddress":ip, "station":req.params.stationname}`, matches  your existing document in the listeners collection. I tried this and it works as expected, you just need to be more careful.